# How to push an image to the right of each menu item block

Tags: html, css, css-float, absolute

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/86wj0qem/

Code as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="subnav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li> 
            <a href="#">Top menu thing useful</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Second entry in the menu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Entry number 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 4 has sub menu!</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">As promised, menu 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The last menu option is 4.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#subnav {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
}
#subnav .nav {
    width: 215px;
    font-size: 70%;
    position: relative;
}
#subnav .nav li {
    width: 210px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 2PX 0PX 2PX !important;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3px 0px;
}
#subnav .nav li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
}
#subnav .nav li ul {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
#subnav .nav li ul li {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
#subnav .nav li:after {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    content: url("http://s10.postimg.org/eh8ghojkl/arrowg.png");
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The problem, as highlighted by the fiddle, is the images don't push to the right side of each LI item in this specific list.  I want it to work no matter what text is in there, and don't want it to repeat if the menu item goes over 1 line.

I cannot modify the html as this is generated.  I also tried using an absolute position with right: 0 and got much the same result.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS specifies your image to be after the `li` which I think should be after the `a` inside the `li`. I changed that and adapted margins. Here's the updated code :

```
#subnav .nav li a:after {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    content: url("http://s10.postimg.org/eh8ghojkl/arrowg.png");
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86wj0qem/2/).

Comment: Actually, it wasn't the first question http://i.imgur.com/4BdrYzz.png but it's ok ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
#subnav .nav li {
width: 210px;
height: 25px;
margin: 2PX 0PX 2PX !important;
background-color: #CECECE;
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 3px 0px;
position: relative;
}
#subnav .nav li:after {
/* float: right; */
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
margin-top: 7px;
content: url("http://s10.postimg.org/eh8ghojkl/arrowg.png");
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xr1ar5z9/

If you want me to explain this, I just used `position:absolute` for the arrows, and `position:relative` for the list items, so the `<li>` element properly contains the absolute-positioned arrow. Had this problem many many times, and this is the best way I use to solve it :)